# Thunderbird has started to leave automatically flame-market junk in inbox instead of moving it to Junk folder. How to fix?

Tags: thunderbird, spam-prevention

Thunderbird used to move mail that it marked as junk to the junk folder, but now many messages that have been automatically designated junk (with the flame marker) are left in the inbox.  What's the explanation and what's the fix?  All my settings are adjusted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If all other Junk settings are fine, I'd reinitialize the training data - something there is maybe corrupted/confused.

**Important: this will make TB to restart from scratch; you'll get more Junk at the beginning!**

In Thunderbird select Thunderbird–>Preferences from the menu.

Click on “Security.”

Select the “Junk” section.

Click the “Reset Training Data” button on the bottom right.

Not sure if it's important, but then I'd close TB and restart it.
If you still have some actual SPAMs in an box, then train again the spam recognition on those samples.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.